# Add enum value to a ruby on rails model and make it default for all new model instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums, model

I have an enum like this defined in a model

```
enum status: { started: "started", passed: "passed", failed: "failed" }
```

I want to add value `draft: "draft"` to it

But as far as I understand I have to run a migration somehow for it to be added to the database. How would I do it?
Might be a stupid question, please bear with me, thanks.

:edit
Thanks for the feedback

I also need to make the newly added enum values the default for all the new models. This will likely need a migration, but how would I generate it?

Comment: What would that migration do? I think you can add a new value to this enum and start using it.

Comment: If that is the case I will add a little bit more to the question, thanks for you input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an enum value to the list.

```
enum status: { started: "started", passed: "passed", failed: "failed", draft: "draft" }
```

If the enum was an array, you'd have to be sure to add the new value to the end of the array only, otherwise records would have the wrong status.

As for making it the default for new records, I would do this in the model, not the database...

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :initialize_status

  private

  def initialize_status
    self.status ||= 'draft' if new_record?
  end
end
```

Comment: That's true for array declarations: `enum status: [ :active, :archived ]`. There's an implicit mapping there (symbol to integer (array index)). But here, the mapping is explicit. You sure that placing the new KV pair in front of the list would make records have wrong statuses?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev   yes, you're right, hashes are immune to the problem, my bad. Answer corrected.

Comment: That's better  The real question is about the migration, though (make the new value default for the new rows)

Comment: Another good point @SergioTulentsev, modified answer.